# How do I calculate Work Item Rejection Rate in Rally?

Tags: rally

Has anyone been able to calculate the rejection rate for work items in Rally? For example, how many times a Defect goes from Complete back to In Progress.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can get to this app: https://github.com/RallyTechServices/cycle-time-apps/tree/master/kickbacks